# Error al instalar Visual Studio IDE 2019

Tags: visual-studio, windows10, visual-studio-2019

Estoy instalando el IDE de Visual Studio 2019 en el Disco D, dado que no tengo suficiente espacio para instalarlo en el Disco C. El problema sucede que en mitad de la instalación de Visual Studio 2019 me aparece el siguiente cuadro:

[image: Error Visual Studio]

Cabe recalcar que tenía instalado el Visual Studio 2022 anteriormente, luego lo desinstalé para comprobar si instalaba de correctamente, pero igual me aparece aquel mensaje dicho anteriormente.

Comment: ¿Qué dice el mensaje de error? No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que verificar 2 cosas, la versión que quieras escoger

- Community (VSC - Visual Studio Code)
- Profesional (MVC - Microsoft Visual Studio)

El community es con su logo azul que puedes descargar sin ningún "problema"
El que estas descargando es la version "pro", y eso te puede estar pasando por que has descargado mas cosas con el instalador, si te aparece la pantalla de paquetes que quieras instalar, no marques ninguno, ya que los programas ahí pesan demasiado(me paso a mi por querer instalar software y termina descargando paquetes con mas peso, por ende mi pc no aguantaba la cantidad de descarga)

Recomendaciíon:

- Panel de Control> Desinstala todo
- Comprueba que visual studio quieres:

> https://code.visualstudio.com/ 
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/es/vs/

- Elige versiones community si no tienes licencia
- No descargues nada, a pesar de lenguajes que vayas a usar, ya que pueden aumentar la carga del programa
- Al finalizar la Instalación, empieza a descargar los programas que te sean necesarios.